# Ford Fusion 2014 Ecoboost Stops 2 seconds after Starting

Tags: ford, fusion

After stopping, the console shows the following error
`Steering Assist Fault Service Req'd`
The `Traction Control` lights are both On.
This doesn't happen when the engine is on though.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is your question?

Comment: A repeated 2-second shutoff suggests that the engine immobilizer is being activated. The two lights may well be unrelated to the turns-off issue.